# Cannot cast from XPathExpression<Object> to XPathExpression<Content>

Tags: java, jdom

I'm trying to write a method to execute a JDOM2 XPath.  I would like to be able to pass in any type of filter (e.g. `Filter<Content>` or `Filter<Element>`.  I'm passing in an Element.  Element is an interface that extends the Content filter.  The compiler warns

"The method `executeXPath(Document, String, String, Filter<Content>`) in the type XMLUtilities is not applicable for the arguments `(Document, String, String, Filter<Element>)`"

Is there a way to do this without having to create a separate method for each of the Content types?

```
Filter<Element> filter = new org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter();
List<Element> xPathSearchedNodes = XMLUtilities.executeXPath(doc, "/x:root","http://www.example.com",filter);
```

....

```
static public List<Content> executeXPath(Document document, String xpathStr, String namespace, Filter<Content> filter) {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your method generic:

```
static public <T extends Content> List<T> executeXPath(Document document, String xpathStr, String namespace, Filter<T> filter) {...}
```

If you pass it a `Filter<Content>` it returns a `List<Content>`, if you pass it a `Filter<Element>` it'll return a `List<Element>`, etc.

Comment: I had to use "<? extends Content>" for the compiler not to complain, then in the client cast this to List<Element>.